# javascript map function Array push not working

Tags: javascript

```
const allOrderStatus = ["afterPayment", "checkedOrder", "delayedDelivery"];

let dataCount = [];
allOrderStatus.map(async (item) => {
  const result = await this.model.countDocuments({
    orderStatus: item,
    sellerId: "5fe8d891bbefb5287c76e95c",
  });
  dataCount.push({ item: result });
});

console.log(dataCount);
```

If you use the for statement, it works fine, but if you use the map function, only the empty array exists in the dataCount. What's the reason?

Comment: You might want to re-read what `.map()` does and how.

Comment: `.forEach` instead `.map`

Comment: Also relevant: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086) and [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685)

Comment: In your code, `allOrderStatus.map()` returns an array of [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)s that nobody [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)s to settle. `console.log(dataCount);` does not print anything because the code that puts data in `dataCount` didn't run yet. You have to pass the return value of `allOrderStatus.map()` to [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and `await` the returned `Promise`.